# how to use QFtp::list and QFtp::listInfo to check if directory exists

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qt5

I try to make ftp uploader which creates automatically subdirectories and put files in them.

My problem is that:

- my uploader doesn't upload files if directory already exists.
- it fails on next mkdir (no error just it doesnt upload file).

I know QFtp have `list()` and `listInfo()` but I don't understand how I should use in my code.

Here is how I implemented my uploader:

```
ftp = new QFtp();
ftp->setTransferMode(QFtp::Passive);

ftp->connectToHost(g.ftp_host);
ftp->login(g.ftp_user,g.ftp_password);
ftp->list();
ftp->cd(g.ftp_defaultdir+g.phocadir);

for (int i = 0; i<FulluploadFilenames->size(); i++){
    ftp->mkdir(_taj->at(i)); // should check if exists
    ftp->cd(_taj->at(i));
    ftp->mkdir(_year->at(i));
    ftp->cd(_year->at(i));
    ftp->mkdir(_month->at(i));
    ftp->cd(_month->at(i));

    qdata = new QFile(FulluploadFilenames->at(i),this);
    if (qdata->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        ftp->put(qdata,uploadFilenames->at(i));
        ftp->list();
    }

    ftp->cd("../");
    ftp->cd("../");
    ftp->cd("../");
}
ftp->close();
```

This make and cd to something like this: `/123123123/2015/05/` and uploads file here.

Could somebody please help how to check if directory exists?

**UPDATE:**

Instead of checking if directories exists I forced mkdir to work in sync so it doesn't matter if fails.

```
void MainWindow::doUpload(){ 
ftp = new QFtp();
ftp->connectToHost(g.ftp_host);
ftp->login(g.ftp_user,g.ftp_password);
ftp->cd(g.ftp_defaultdir+g.phocadir);
ftp->list();
// making directories
for (int i = 0; i<FulluploadFilenames->size(); i++){
    runCommand(ftp, ftp->mkdir(_taj->at(i)));
    runCommand(ftp, ftp->mkdir(_taj->at(i)+"/"+_year->at(i)));
    runCommand(ftp, ftp->mkdir(_taj->at(i)+"/"+_year->at(i)+"/"+_month->at(i)));
}
// uploading files
for (int i = 0; i<FulluploadFilenames->size(); i++){
    ftp->cd(_taj->at(i)+"/"+_year->at(i)+"/"+_month->at(i));

    qdata = new QFile(FulluploadFilenames->at(i),this);
    if (qdata->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        ftp->put(qdata,uploadFilenames->at(i));
    }

    ftp->cd("../../../");

    ui->progressBar->setValue(i+1);
    ui->progressBar->update();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
ftp->close();
}
```

...

```
void MainWindow::runCommand(QFtp *ftp, int commandId){
QEventLoop loop;
connect(ftp, SIGNAL(commandFinished(int, bool)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `list()` work asynchronously. After you call this function it immediately returns unique identifier. This id passed in `commandStarted()` signal when command started and in `commandFinished()` signal when list command finished. Between this two signals `listInfo()` signal is emitted for each directory entry found.

So before upload to directory you must check all `QUrlInfo` objects, passed from `listInfo()` signals until `commandFinished()` signal emitted.